# Disable shipping address with react-paypal-js

Tags: reactjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

Hi I am using this module to integrate the Paypal solution in my site: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/react-paypal-js

However even though it seems to be developed by paypal officially, there seems to be no option to disable the shipping address during checkout

```
<PayPalScriptProvider options={{ "client-id": clientId, currency: "GBP", "disable-funding": "sofort", shippingPreference: "NO_SHIPPING" }}>
```

Doesn't seem to have any effect at the checkout page as it still shows the delivery address

[image: Doesn't seem to have any effect at the checkout page as it still shows the delivery address]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After digging through the source code you can supply many options.. I was able to set no shipping address like this:

```
 const createOrder = (data, actions) => {
          return actions.order
              .create({
                  purchase_units: [
                      {
                          amount: {
                              value: donationAmount,
                          },
                      },
                  ],
                  application_context: {
                      shipping_preference: "NO_SHIPPING"
                  }
              })
              .then((orderID) => {
                  setOrderID(orderID);
                  return orderID;
              });
      }

<PayPalButtons style={{ layout: "vertical" }} createOrder={createOrder} />
```